# Import several excel sheets into one table in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I have eight Excel sheets, all with two columns a 13000 rows each. I want to create a table in my database with all this data. Also, I want the rows in the different sheets to match each other, meaning that row 1 in each of the columns in all the sheets, should form one row in the database. Is there any convenient way of doing so?

Comment: you mean, is there a way to import your 8 sheets as a single table in Oracle? the answer is 'yes,' SQL Developer has a wizard for that

Comment: Yes, but if you import the sheets one by one, they are not loaded in on the same rows. The first one will generate 13000 rows, the second one will generate row13001-26000 and so on.

Comment: ahhh, so you want inserts, and then updates. yeah, no easy way via the UI. you'd be better to merge the 8 spreadsheets first, then insert the data to Oracle